# Remove arguments from UninstallString

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

I'm extracting the uninstall string from the Chrome uninstaller for an unattended silent uninstall using this:

```
$UninstallStrings = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
    Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like $ProgramName} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString -ea SilentlyContinue
```

which gives me this result:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\67.0.3396.79\Installer\setup.exe" --uninstall --system-level
```

Now to proceed to uninstall I guess I need to trim the arguments off of the result and then do a `Start-Process`. Anyone can hint the right way of removing the arguments and adding them as the `-ArgumentsList` after?

Comment: `$UninstallStrings | Invoke-Expression`

Comment: Receive error "Unexpected token 'uninstall' in expression or statement." using $UninstallStrings | Invoke-Expression. I want to trim off the --uninstall...... bit and add a different set of variables to the .exe defined at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Try `$UninstallStrings -replace '^', '& ' | Invoke-Expression`.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty simple way I can think of to get just the install path is to do a split based on the special character used to initiate the arguments, in this case, '--', followed by selecting the first entry in the resulting array.

For example, if you're at this point:

```
$UninstallStrings = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |
Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like $ProgramName} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString -ea SilentlyContinue
```

You can then take that variable, split it like this:

```
$ExpandedUninstallString = $UninstallStrings -split "--"
$UninstallCommand = $ExpandedUninstallString[0]
$Arguments = $ExpandedUninstallString[1..($ExpandedUninstallString.Length)]
```

Which should set $UninstallCommand equal to a string pointing to just the uninstaller, and also setting up the existing arguments in that $Arguments array.

Also note that this is not expandable to cover other applications unless you tailor it with some if statements to check for  what character the installstring is using as arguments for that particular application, and tailor the split delimiter to that particular argument list.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ProgramName = "Google Chrome"
$EXEArgumente = "--uninstall --force-uninstall --system-level"
$UninstallStrings = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WoW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | Where-Object{$_.DisplayName -like $ProgramName} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString -ea SilentlyContinue

$ExpandedUninstallString = $UninstallStrings -split "--" -replace "`"",""
$UninstallCommand = $ExpandedUninstallString[0]

Start-Process $UninstallCommand -ArgumentList "$EXEArgumente"
```

This is how I got it working now. Thanks for all the help!